# Show file name with css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have just javascript and css. But want to show the uploaded file name

Googled a lot

So I have this as css:

```
.metadata .filename{
  font-size: 10px;
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and this is the js code:

```
var messagetext = '';
messagetext += '<span class="metadata">' + '<span class="filename">' + file.name + '</span>';
```

But if I do a `console.log(file.name)` then I see the name of the uploaded file in the console.

But I dont see it in the view.

Thank you

this is the whole function:

```
$('body').on('change', '#upload-input', function () {

  var halloText = 'file';
    var files = $(this).get(0).files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        // create a FormData object which will be sent as the data payload in the
        // AJAX request
        var formData = new FormData();
        // loop through all the selected files and add them to the formData object
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            var message = buildMessage(myUserId, new Date().toISOString(), '<div class="imagepreview"><canvas id="progress' + imagecounter + '" width="80" height="80"></canvas><img id="image' + imagecounter + '"/></div>', 'sent');
            message.classList.add('imagesender');
            message.classList.add('imagesender' + imagecounter);
            conversation.appendChild(message);
            //processImages();
            conversation.scrollTop = conversation.scrollHeight;
            var myCanvas = document.getElementById('progress' + imagecounter);
            var circle = new ProgressCircle({
                canvas: myCanvas,
            });
            var percentComplete = 0.65;
            circle.addEntry({
                minRadius: 30,
                fillColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                progressListener: function () {
                    return percentComplete; // between 0 and 1
                }
            });
            circle.start(33);
            var extn = file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

            if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.id = imagecounter;
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var imageid = imagecounter;
                        document.getElementById("image" + e.currentTarget.id).src = e.target.result;

                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                } else {
                    // No filereader support... so no preview
                }
            }
            imagecounter++;
            // add the files to formData object for the data payload
            formData.append('uploads[]', file, file.name);
        }
        formData.append('Token', SessionInfo.ImageToken);
        formData.append('RoomId', currentRoom.RoomId);
        dbgMessage(formData);
        $.ajax({
            url: apipath + '/devices/UploadData',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            done: function (data) {

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                //show error as a message
                var message = buildMessage(myUserId, new Date().toISOString(), jqXHR.responseText, 'error');
                conversation.appendChild(message);
                conversation.scrollTop = conversation.scrollHeight;
            },
            xhr: function () {
                // create an XMLHttpRequest
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                // listen to the 'progress' event
                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        // calculate the percentage of upload completed
                        percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;

                        if (percentComplete == 1) {
                         var messagetext = '';
                         messagetext += '<span class="metadata">' + '<span class="filename">' + file.name + '</span>';
                            // Handle complete
                            $('.imagesender').hide();
                            dbgMessage('Upload complete ');
                            console.log(file.name);
                        }
                    }
                }, false);
                return xhr;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

So that the file name will be visible in the html view.

if I do this:

```
$('.messagewrapper').append('<span class="metadata">' + '<span class="filename">' + file.name + '</span>');
```

Then it works only after I upload file.

But When I refresh the page the image file is not visible anymore

Like this:

```
 if (percentComplete == 1) {
                                // Handle complete
                                $('.imagesender').hide();
                                dbgMessage('Upload complete ');
                            }
                            $('.messagewrapper').append("<p>"+ file.name+"</p>")
```

Comment: Can you show your full code, where is file came from where is located and what you do to `messagetext`? What is your html code? Only this do nothing.

Comment: `messagetext` is a variable ... javascript variables aren't displayed in a web page

Comment: Indent your code please

Comment: you have to append `messagetext ` to some element which I cant see you are doing. Do something like this `conversation.appendChild(message);`

Comment: well why would it be visible after you refresh the page?

Comment: ? I don't know ok

Comment: It is a page load and all the code that ran has been reset. The page does not maintain state.

Comment: But I have a file upload icon and that also stays after refresh. so to fix that then?

Comment: How to keep the state then? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

append based on id like this should work:

`$('#messagewrapper').append("<p>"+ file.name+"</p>")`

You will append this only when the file is uploaded because it is inside the `if` statement:
`percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
   if (percentComplete == 1){ //==1 means uploaded
//your append is here`

So move it outside the `if` statement.

Comment: So you mean like this:  if (percentComplete == 1) {
                                // Handle complete
                                $('.imagesender').hide();
                                dbgMessage('Upload complete ');
                            }
                            $('.messagewrapper').append("<p>"+ file.name+"</p>")